# Storing data from Python to MySQL on Raspberry Pi3, Trouble fetching and using the same data

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I've been trying to get a Python script to save a value to a MySQL database, and that's been going well. 
The data I have stored is the integer 60 in the column `NIGHT_SECONDS` in the table `weather_settings`.
However when I try to get the data out to use in another script, seem to get the value `((60L,),)`.
I have tried googling this and I have no luck. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
def gettime():
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pass","weather")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    try:
        sql = "select NIGHT_SECONDS from weather_settings"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        global delay
        delay = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Data fetched from MySQL")
        #print(delay)
        print(delay)

    except:
        print("Database fetching failed")

    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

This is the terminal result:

```
Data fetched from MySQL
((60L,),)
```

And if I try to use this value in `time.sleep(delay)` I get this:

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

So I tried this:

```
delay = float(delay)
```

which didn't work either.

Comment: "So I tried this: delay = float(delay) which didn't work either :)" Adding the error you got will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is what that returned;
delay = float(delay)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `fetchall()` returns a tuple of rows, which themselves are a tuple of column values, so you would need to access it like `delay[0][0]`.

This can be simplified a bit using `fetchone()`:

```
weather_settings_row = cursor.fetchone()
delay = float(weather_settings_row[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick :) I actually tried fetchone and the [0] thing too, but never together, and I would not have thought of it myself so thank you :)